# Axios Post - no console error but not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Axios post is not working, hitting API controller but not hitting corresponding method. Not getting any error in console also.

Get functionality is working fine.

**UI code:**

```
const register =async(companyDetails)=>{
// const ApiURL = await environmentConfig.getBaseURL();
const ApiURL = "https://localhost:44313/api/v1.0";
try{
 const result = await axios(`${ApiURL}/market/company/register`,{
        method:'POST',
        headers :{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
         },
        body :JSON.stringify(companyDetails),
         
    });
    return result.json();
}
catch(err){
    return err;
}
```

}

**API COde**

```
    [Route("api/v1.0/market")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StockController 
    {
        private readonly MongodbService _mongodbService;
        public StockController(MongodbService mongodbService)
        {
            _mongodbService = mongodbService;
        }
    

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("company/register")]
        public async Task<CompanyDetails> Register([FromBody] CompanyDetails companyDetails)
        {
             await _mongodbService.Register(companyDetails);
            return companyDetails;
        }
   }
```

Comment: It may be because your controller not inheriting from `ControllerBase`

Comment: Done but not working!

Comment: Hi @Gayathri, pls F12 in browser to check the `Network` panel if it already sent the request and any response status code here. Also set breakpoint to your backend action if it hit the method to check. If you use asp.net core, are you sure you have put the js code in `@section Scripts{}`?

Comment: I could see 304 error code for Post in network panel

Answer (score 0):

You created a controller but you forgot to specify the method that handles the request. An example on how to program controllers in C# can be found here:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeesController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            if (employee == null)
                return BadRequest();

            var createdEmployee = await employeeRepository.AddEmployee(employee);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetEmployee),
                new { id = createdEmployee.EmployeeId }, createdEmployee);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                "Error creating new employee record");
        }
    }
}
```

I took the example from this [page](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/post-in-aspnet-core-rest-api/).

Comment: No luck! i have added controller base and handled controller with try catch

Comment: Did you specify the [HttpPost]?

Comment: Yes I did specify [HttpPost]

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes we did, sometimes we could see 405 error

Comment: Ok, I assume you saw 405 until you added the method to the controller. Thats generally the case, when the api can't match the request method (post) to a function on the controller. This means your recent question is answered. So what is the current error message?

Comment: Currently I cannot see any error! it is weird !

Comment: What happens when you console.log(result.json()) just before you return result.json()?

Comment: i have added console.log just above the return but nothing is printing in console

Comment: Please return the Ok() from ControllerBase in your Register method

Comment: [Route("company/register")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CompanyDetails>> Register([FromBody] CompanyDetails companyDetails)
        {
            try
            {
                await _mongodbService.Register(companyDetails);
                return Ok(companyDetails);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

Comment: I have added return OK(); but still not working :(

Comment: @ it is hitting dependency injection in controller but not hitting actual method while debugging i noticed this.

Comment: Then you have not registered your dependency injection

Comment: Btw. you can have a look at the terminal to see the error codes of the server

Comment: Please use the following at your WebApplication builder: 
```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
```

Comment: i have added in startup,       services.AddTransient<IMongodbService,MongodbService>();     no luck

Comment: Ok, this is a whole new problem now. The initial question has been answered. Please select this as accepted answer and create a new one for the new problem.

Comment: But to check whether it works or not you could just remove the mongodb service.